# SSL Error when making a request via UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a simple GET request to a site with a valid SSL certificate using UrlFetchApp, but I continuously encounter this error:

```
ScriptError: SSL Error https://dev.kaizena.com/api/config
```

Interestingly enough, the same request works as expected when I make a request to https://kaizena.com/api/config

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var url = "https://dev.kaizena.com/api/config";

var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

var headers = { "Accept":"application/json", 
                "Content-Type":"application/json"//, 
              };

var options = { "method":"GET",
                "contentType" : "application/json",
                "headers": headers,
                "payload" : payload
              }
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
```

Again, the code works as expected if I change the URL to https://kaizena.com/api/config (which also has a valid SSL certificate). Could someone let me know specifically what an "SSL Error" is?

Thanks,
Edward

Comment: Is "dev" a testing subdomain? If so might not support ssl

Comment: It isn't. It's a fully independent server and has its own SSL certificate.

Comment: I don't think this error has anything to do with Apps Script urlFetch.  I think you need to figure out the API for Kaizena.

Comment: Thanks for the response Sandy. I would really like to know more specifically what the "SSL Error" is. Is it an error with the certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with Google not recognizing the provider of the SSL Certificate I used. For reference, I was using PositiveSSL, which provided a valid certificate but didn't seem to make Apps Script very happy. I switched to RapidSSL today and now it all works.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 11):

You can use validateHttpsCertificates to ignore this SSL error.

```
var options = {
  'validateHttpsCertificates' : false
};
  
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Comment: Ignoring the error seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for urlFetchApp is:

```
fetch(url)
```

or

```
fetch(url, params)
```

[urlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

You are creating a payload, header and options, but then not using them.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
```

Should be:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got it from one of the examples that was using POST and so I removed the options param when trying to use GET. Anyways, I tried it with UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options) and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Note once again that the entire thing works with kaizena.com/api/config (without the dev), and dev.kaizena.com is on a separate server with a separate SSL certificate.